# vue3 reactive api in deep object can not re-render

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

template:

```html
<div>
      <label class="label">balance</label>
      <h3 class="title is-4">${{ lobby.balance }}</h3>
</div>
```

code:

```js
setup() {
  const state = reactive({
     lobby: {},
  });

  state.lobby = new Lobby(); //settimeout change balance in constructor is not re-render

  setTimeout(() => {
    state.lobby.balance = 123; // re-render is work
  }, 1000);

  return {
    ...toRefs(state),
  };
}
```

Why isn't the `balance` change in the `Lobby` constructor reactive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would happen when `Lobby()`'s `balance` property is not declared as a [`ref`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref):

```js
class Lobby {
  balance = 0 // ❌ not a ref

  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.balance = 100 // ❌ not a ref, so no reactive
    }, 500)
  }
}
```

The solution would be to declare `balance` as a `ref`:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'

class Lobby {
  balance = ref(0) // 

  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.balance.value = 100 // 
    }, 500)
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-5fjvyn?file=src/components/Lobby.js)